# Disable Elevation in Button in Material-UI in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to disable the **default** elevation of button in material-ui in React.
This code below don't seem to work:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      defaultProps: {
        disableElevation: true
      },
      styleOverrides: {
        
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are using the correct theme to disable the elevation of a button. But after that you need to pass the custom theme to the ThemeProvider. Below is a basic example of disabledElevation button.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider, Button } from '@mui/material';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      defaultProps: {
        disableElevation: true,
      },
    },
  },
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {/* Disabled elevation by theme */}
      <Button variant="contained" sx={{ marginBottom: 4 }}>
        This button has disabled elevation
      </Button>

      {/* Add custom elevation using boxShadow */}
      <Button variant="contained" sx={{ boxShadow: 4 }}>
        This button has disabled elevation
      </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Already did that but so far its not working

Comment: Its working in the small reproducible example. Are you using mui v5

Comment: Yes, I'm using version `5.1.1`

Comment: Above way is correct recommend by mui and its working in small example. So, check your import and theme provider and props in a button.

Comment: If you put that one. will it disable all the elevation in Buttons and you won't be able to see the elevation even if you write `elevation={3}` in Buttons?

Comment: no, we are setting defaultProps for elevation. So, we can override it using component props.

Comment: so how can we do the put the default elevation to 0 in global theme but if you add elevation in button, we make it have elevation?

Comment: I have updated a code and image. To add elevation we can use boxShadow.